# Outlier detection methods which can run automatically on multiple univariate time-series?

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

Allow me to state my use-case through a simplified example: coffee-machines. It makes it easier to understand :)

**Challenge:**
I have a series of devices (let's take coffee-machines as example) which each have irregular measurements of maintenance during which a value is measured (let's take the #coffees brewed).
Over-time, each of my >10k coffee-machine would have 1 or more measurements but given limited data-checks occured at input, some data polution might have occured.

e.g.: Coffee Machine A:

```
Time         #Cumulative Cups produced
01-06-2016   65 
01-07-2016   135
15-07-2016   193
23-08-2016   121 => clearly data-pollution
03-10-2016   321
17-10-2016   364
```

**Question:**
Are you aware of any techniques which allow to automatically scan all my Coffee Machine data (>10k Coffee machines) and automatically detect outliners?

**Clarification:**
What do I see as outliers:

- Any decreasing number (as a cumulative number can't decrease)
- Any value not in line with the trend (i.e. trend based on all previous & following values) 
  e.g. if the value '5443' would be measured on '23-08-2016' it would be very likely to be an outliner.

Comment: I can't see why 121 is an outlier unless somehow by nature you know the number must increase.  In that case the outlier is defined as the first decrease.  I assume you mean something more general but it is not well explained.

Comment: Apologies @MichaelChernick ; added some clarification as edit. Key of defining a value as an outlier would be that it's out-of-trend with the values before & after. The ideal methodology I'm looking for would take into account the time-slots, create a trend & define for each value a 'probability' of being an outlier.

Comment: Time series data is a collection of transactions for a specific bucket of time. It is often incorrectly/inefficiently analyzed as a cumulative as you are doing . For example total ticket sales for a movie start at zero and then increase. If you analyze the actual new tickets sales per day or per week you can then get a simplified  model that does not include an induced differencing operator due to the cumulant being analyzed. I suggest that you analyze the # of new ocurrences with a negative clearly being an outlier thus examine/model the data in the dis-aggregate.

Comment: I voted to close because even for one series as in the case of machine A with 6 time points there are way to many ways to define outliers and some could be automated,  But note that the OP wants to look at an ensemble of over 10,000 time series.  Can we consider the machines to be partial realizations of the same process?  How would you know? although the OP has now added more detail in comment but I don't think it helps. Why assume a trend? Assuming a trend means monotonically increasing it could be a line or a nonlinear curve and shouldn't we allow for random variation around the curve?

Answer (score -2):

What do you plan to do with the outliers you detect?  Deleting them without verifying that they are indeed mistakes is problematic.  Perhaps you might want to just leave them in and consider analysis methods that are resistant to the presence of outliers.  Or do you hope to learn something from the outliers themselves?

Comment: Hi Emil; deleting for sure not; rather hiding them for reporting/user dashboards. Additionally one could/would indeed analyze the outliers & understand the root-cause of why a wrong measure was logged.

Comment: Why TWO downvotes?